# Retrieve Build Cause/Reason from Azure Pipelines?

Tags: azure, rest, azure-pipelines

I am using the Azure DevOps REST API, for example:

```
curl -X GET 'https://dev.azure.com/MyOrg/MyProject/_apis/pipelines/ID/runs/ID?api-version=6.0-preview.1'
```

In the result, there does not seem to be any mention of the *parameters* passed into the pipeline, or the *build cause/reason*. I've tried setting variables to the value of the parameters and that doesn't seem to show up either, and fiddling with the API version string hasn't yielded anything.

Is there a way to programmatically retrieve information about trigger reason and parameters using the API? Without this, it seems impossible to build any backend data (for example, to show the % of users using your pipeline via the azure portal or via PR triggers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [Builds - Get](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/get?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) api instead:

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/builds/{buildId}?api-version=6.0
```

You would get `triggerInfo` and `reason` in the response.